# spring-boot requestMapping stopped working after adding enableCaching

Tags: caching, spring-boot, couchbase, ehcache

My spring boot(1.3.5) application uses couchbase(2.0) and exposes rest controller. I can access data from couchbase and browser shows it as a response. NO issues here.

Now I want to use ehcache. When I add @EnableCaching in the main application class, rest service stops working. In the logs it says 'did not find any matchers for the request'

https://github.com/maverickmicky/spring-couchbase-cache

Comment: Can you provide an example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi Andy, I have added the source code.

Comment: Once I'd pieced it back together, the code you've shared works for me. Perhaps you can share a Git repo or similar that illustrates the problem so that people can be sure they're running the exact same code as you are

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for trying it.
To provide you with fresh source, I cleaned up as I cannot share the original one. After trimming down, it starts working. The only change after trimming the app was in the implementation of AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration class, it asked me to update the method name from getBootstrapHosts() to bootstrapHosts()
Probably there was some version mismatch.